# Automatically update document in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB and Node.js. Let's say we have two users:

```
{
    "name": "user1",
    "email": "user1@email.com",
    "pairedWith": "user2@email.com",
    "paired": false,
}
```

and

```
{
    "name": "user2",
    "email": "user2@email.com",
    "pairedWith": "user1@email.com",
    "paired": false,
}
```

They can pair with each other by searching for the correct email address. After **both** users searched for the email and paired with each other, I want the `paired` field to become `true` **automatically**. Only after both users have paired. Of course here user1 must be paired with user2, and user2 must be paired with user1 because they specifically wanted that.

So how do I tell MongoDB to update **paired to true automatically** once 2 users are paired? *Based on this true value, I will display something for both of them, but until it's not true, I can't.*

Answer (score 1):

you can add an additional field for entered_correct email.
So, if user1 enters correct email set it to true.
now, when user2 enters correct email for user1 set it to true.

both times check in another user's document if entered_correct is true there. When both documents have entered_correct true, set paired to true in both of them.